# Using Android Studio how do you modify the onTextChange function to allow you to filter out results depending on the class elements of the items

Tags: java, android, textwatcher, addtextchangedlistener

I am learning java and android studio and I am trying to make a menu with each food item being an individual class with a set of allergens either having true or false value. I add the objects of each class into an ArrayList to display them using a list view. I have implemented a search bar that works correctly, however, I am trying to modify the `onTextChanged` function so if for example the user types in "gluten" it will return all food items that DO NOT contain that allergen.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


//Test Classes for now will be added into a different file once working as intended.
 class Pad_Thai{
     public
     String name = "Pad Thai";
     boolean gluten = false;
     boolean shellfish = true;

        }
        class Fried_Rice{
     public
     String name = "Fried Rice";
            boolean gluten = true;
            boolean shellfish = true;
        }
class Beef_Broc{
    public
    String name = "Beef & Broc";
    boolean gluten = true;
    boolean shellfish = true;
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter2;
    private ArrayAdapter tempadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theList);
        EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started.");

        //Creating Objects of the Specified classes
        Pad_Thai obj = new Pad_Thai();
        Beef_Broc obj2= new Beef_Broc();
        Fried_Rice obj3= new Fried_Rice();

        //array of an object of classes
        final ArrayList<String> food = new ArrayList<>();
        //testing array
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        food.add(obj.name);
        food.add(obj2.name);
        food.add(obj3.name);

        names.add("Orange Chicken");
        names.add("Pad Thai");
        names.add("Fried Rice");
        names.add("Beef and Broc");
        names.add("Special Tempora");


        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, food);
        adapter2 =  new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);


        list.setAdapter(adapter);

       theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           @Override
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
               (MainActivity.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);


               if (charSequence == "gluten") {

                   ArrayList<String> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                   for (int t  = 0; t < tempArrayList.size() ; t++) {
                       if (food[t].gluten == false) {
                           tempArrayList.add(food.get(t));
                       }
                   }

                   tempadapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempArrayList);
                   list.setAdapter(tempadapter);
               }

              // ArrayList<String> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
              // for (int t  = 0; t < tempArrayList.size() ; t++) {
               //   if ([t].gluten() == false) {
              //         tempArrayList.add(c);
               //    }
               //}
               //mAdapter = new food(activity, tempArrayList);
               //lv.setAdapter(madapter);

           }

           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

           }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: what you mean by allergen?

Comment: so each class has boolean data members being either true or false. Gluten and shellfish are allergens( popular allergies people have)
The ending question it would return all results that do not contain in this example gluten, as thats the method I attempted to implement.